# JSON server on Android

Tags: android, json, rest

I'm new in Android development. I have a lot of file .JSON that I want to take by REST requests in my app. Is there a JSON local server for Android where I can save these file and do some REST requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go through with this url :- 
https://github.com/typicode/json-server.

Comment: And also go through with some basics of JSON

Comment: if you require this for POC purpose then you can use FireBase. It lets you save entire json and then exposes a library to sync it with app.

Comment: @susheeltickoo FireBase maintain JSON tree.

Comment: I try to install JSON-server but it doesn't work. With $ npm install -g json-server it give me a lot of error

Comment: Ok, I manage to install json-server, but how i can interact with it in my app? What URL I have to type in the Rest request?

Comment: All uses direction are given in  `README.md ` so go through with it @Quarillion

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand how I can use json-server on Android

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled to and used [`SyncAdapter`](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Server-Synchronization-(SyncAdapter)) and json-server to firebase and I treated android like a web-app

I noticed that the guide used uri and json parsing so I imported my fake rest `db.json` to firebase and used the link on `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/new-firebase-app/database/data`

```
...
final String rest = "https://new-firebase-app.firebaseio.com/people.json";

// Parse the pretend json news feed
String jsonFeed = download(rest);

JSONArray jsonPeople = new JSONArray(jsonFeed);
...
```

This might help.